# The volume level doesn't change in a windows phone 8.1 slider

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, slider, windows-phone-8.1, volume

I am trying to change the valume of the phone while song is playing.
I did that:

```
        BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.Volume = (double)VolumeSlider.Value;
```

but, when I use the slider, it only turns music off when its on zero, and on otherwise, but it doesnt change the level.

Answer (score 1):

Note that, the volume range is 0~1. 
You must divide slider value by slider maximum.

```
BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.Volume = (double)VolumeSlider.Value/VolumeSlider.Maximum;
```

Answer (score 0):

MediaElement volume range 0-1. So, you should set the slider value within this range.

```
<Slider Name="VolumeSlider"
        Background="White"                                 
        Foreground="Red"
        Minimum="0"
        Maximum="1"
        SmallChange="0.1"
        LargeChange="0.2"
        Value ="0.5" />

 BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.Volume = (double)VolumeSlider.Value;
```